# how to return all the rows if I filter a column by a NULL value, instead of returning nothing

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Somebody knows how to return all the rows if I filter a column by a NULL value, instead of returning nothing?

ps. I'm using python

my code:

```
x = ''

conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT column_1 FROM table_1 WHERE column_1 = '" + x + "'")
```

the code now return nothing..

Thanks

Comment: what does 'filter a column by a null value' mean?  Please provide sample input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

I don't use python but try something like this

```
...
 if (x==""): whereString=""
  else: 
     whereString="where column_1='"+ x+"'"

     cur.execute("SELECT column_1 FROM table_1 "+whereString)
 ...
```